# Use Trianglify for site background?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to set my site background with [Trianglify](https://github.com/qrohlf/trianglify). The site I am trying to use it with is [here](https://test.sneakysneaky.tk). It doesn't have any scrolling. None of the examples work for me (they all place the generated image below the rest of the content, not as the background). I also tried the suggestion in [issue #58](https://github.com/qrohlf/trianglify/issues/58) but that didn't work at all. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just change the position of your element that contains the background with CSS. I hope this answer to you question.

```css
canvas {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<h1>Title</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam vitae purus quis dolor lacinia gravida. Ut sit amet purus vel tellus faucibus posuere. Pellentesque ut sapien quis elit luctus tincidunt. Etiam eros nisl, semper sit amet malesuada et, aliquet id arcu. Quisque leo ipsum, ullamcorper nec urna ac, maximus finibus tortor. Curabitur non justo condimentum, consectetur diam sed, lobortis lorem. Nulla scelerisque hendrerit nunc, eu aliquam est pretium vel. Maecenas risus mi, ultrices eget mollis sed, consectetur id eros. Donec ac mauris mattis, tincidunt lacus sit amet, congue lacus. Vivamus sed nulla sit amet dolor porttitor dictum. Cras quis mi massa. Quisque lobortis consequat ante sit amet blandit. In dictum iaculis elementum. Maecenas quis congue eros. Phasellus aliquam, libero ut fermentum accumsan, quam sem egestas elit, vel posuere purus dui id mauris. Praesent vel risus ac felis dapibus finibus in nec enim.</p>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/trianglify/1.1.0/trianglify.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var pattern = Trianglify({
        width: window.innerWidth,
        height: window.innerHeight,
        cell_size: 30 + Math.random() * 100,
        x_colors: 'random',
        y_colors: 'match_x',
        stroke_width: 3
    });
    document.body.appendChild(pattern.canvas())
</script>
```

edit: First expand snippet, then run code.

edit2: Forgot `left: 0`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked pretty well. Except now I have a white bar down the left side that pushes the canvas over to the right. I checked my window size and the script is making the canvas properly. Could you please have a quick look at [my HTML](https://pastebin.com/efk76y1b) to see if you can notice anything? This issue seems to be present in that snippet as well.

Comment: I was messing around with some other stuff and changed some of the positioning stuff on the <body> and it fixed the issue. [HTML is here](https://pastebin.com/Z1V9AKGc) I'm not sure why but hey it works. Thanks again!

Comment: I seem to have forgotten `left: 0;` at the `canvas`. I'm so sorry that I had to put you through that, but yours also work! If you want you can use your old `body` code and add the `left: 0`, up to you.